# GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, identity

I keep getting an intermittent, sporadic error in production with ASP.NET Identity's `UserManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken`. It's like the phone number is null, but it never is!

Added debugging messages and exception handling to re-try the call to `GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken`, tried resetting the `UserManager` to null so it can be reset.

```cs
var code = UserManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken(AcccountId, SMSPhone);
```

Most of the time this line of code works fine, it generates a code that is sent to the user's SMS for verification.

However maybe 2% of the time, it returns the error below.

> System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String.
>   Parameter name: s
>
> at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
>   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.d__123.MoveNext()
>
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>
>   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.d__124.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)

SMSPhone is NEVER null, even the form submitted shows a 10 digit phone number every single time. `AccountId` is always a positive integer as well.

Update - this is in the asp.net identity source code I downloaded from codeplex, I guess the users with this issue may not have had security stamps after not having logged in after our update to ASP.NET Identity. I'm doing an 'UpdateSecurityStamp' call just before now, we'll see if it works.

Comment: What is the parameter `s` ?

Comment: The problem could be in the auth code

Comment: @Marco I don't know what parameter s is, it's internal to the source code of GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken. I'm assuming it's the phone number, as AccountId is int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the missing security stamp on the asp net identity 'User' table. We called the UpdateSecurityStamp method to fill in the null timestamps with real values (GUIDs I believe), then no more error.